# How add related attributes like country+state+city+area in magento?

Tags: attributes, e-commerce, product, magento-1.8

I am trying to add location of the product, how can I do that as states,cities and areas are related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension, its free:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-locator.html

Comment: I don't want use an extension. I will prefer build my own extension. How can I do that?

Comment: you've developed some extension for magento?